# Cannot use both Session and JWT Auth in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

I am using Laravel 5.5 with JWT `dev-develop`. I have also set my auth drivers for web.

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

But, the above configuration doesn't give me JWT Bearer Token. When I replace `web` with `api`, `Auth::attempt($credentials)` gives me JWT token instead of session.

Any ideas how to use both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth::attempt($credentials)` override actual method when you using `JWT` and giving you JWT Token.

You can also check this function in `tymon\src\JWTAuth.php`

You can both as use default `guard` as as `web` and use

`JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)` to get JWT Token

Comment: is there any way I can use both of them?

Comment: I have been using `JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)` but this isn't working at all. I cannot get user credentials. Here's what I did in my JWTAuthentication middleware `$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
       app('auth')->setUser($user);`

Comment: I am getting bearer token but it does not get validated while passing through middleware `app('auth')->setUser($user)`

Comment: which middleware ? share name ? it should be `auth:api` in api.php